# Blob of falling water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, meteorology

If a "blob" of about 100-200ml of water is dropped from higher than about a first floor (using English nomenclature: ground, first floor, second, etc), it'll stay together as a blob until it's about 2 metres above the ground, then burst into droplets. The height of the drop point doesn't change the height of the "bursting apart" point.

I've tried this in both north and south hemispheres, at altitudes from sea level to about 8000 feet, and from heights of first floor to 16th floor. I've only used blobs of 100-200ml, so don't know if larger blobs exhibit the same behaviour. I haven't tried it over water. If there's a strong wind it can tear the blob apart very quickly, so it won't work from an aircraft.

A way to ensure reasonably consistent sized blobs is to put the required amount of water into a balloon, hold it above the drop point, and puncture it with a pin.

My first thought was that when the blob was moving fast enough the air pressure will force it to burst apart, but if that were the case it would burst the same distance down from the drop point. It doesn't. It's always a couple of metres above the ground. It seems to reach terminal velocity pretty quickly, so it's something to do with its proximity to the ground. When I learned to fly I learned about ground effect and thought that might be an answer, but that's a consequence of the downwash from the wings (or rotor, in a helicopter.) I read somewhere once that a blob of water will burst apart if its Reynolds number is above about 65000, but don't really know how to measure it.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this behaviour (the blob bursting apart the same height above the ground, regardless of how far it's fallen.)

(This is not the same as [Orientation of large water drops break-up](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135319/orientation-of-large-water-drops-break-up).)

Comment: Did you have someone on the ground taking videos?

Comment: Assuming full repeatability, etc., I would also suspect ground-effect backpressure.

Comment: @R.W.Bird yes; the burst point was consistent, but parallax issues prevented accurate measurements.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft full repeatability: every time I've tried the experiment I've had the same result.